# How to precompile components of Angular 2 rc1 project

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

It happens that we have here a pretty big Angular2 application and as recently Angluar RC1 came out I was updating our app to that sub npm module layout. 
While doing that I noticed that from rc1 we have ability to use bootstrapStatic method invoking which should let us be free of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic and @angular/compiler which would spare us some 1 mb of JS to download.

Hence the question - are there anyone that could tell me how exactly I should precompile @angular components so they can be used with bootstrapStatic?

It's not like I haven't tried on my own. I know there is a @angular/compiler-cli but sadly enough it doesn't seem to be compatible with rc1 as latest version is compiled for rc0.

And even if that would be running, I have a clue how to precompile root component, but what should I do about tons of components that are created via ComponentResolver.resolveComponent -> ViewContainerRef.createComponent?

I hope that plan is not that I should create a separate component layout that would reference .ngfactory.ts files in stead of real components.

I really do hope someone will be able to help me as this is critical to show that @angular can work real fast to keep it alive in this project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry bro, i totally feel your pain. I'm still trying to create a bundle using jspm on a ng2 hybrid app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time that feature is not supported in the CLI, but it is certainly on the roadmap to be implemented once it has been stabilized in angular core. I mentioned this briefly at the end of my ng-conf talk this year and it was also talked about briefly during the day 2 keynote by Rob Wormald.